# Field _user has not been initialized - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:tezuygulamasi/home_page.dart';
import 'package:tezuygulamasi/sign_in_page.dart';



class LandingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LState createState() => _LState();
}
class _LState extends State<LandingPage> {

  late User _user;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _checkUser();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if(_user == null){
      return SignInPage();
    } else {
      return HomePage(
        user: _user,
      );
    }
  }

  Future<void> _checkUser() async{
    _user = (await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser)!;
  }
}
```

Since the code is written in this way, it gives the error I mentioned in the title. I know the reason for this error is the use of
"late". When I delete it, I run into a problem like this.**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMUX5.png)

Another Page Code

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {

  final User user;
  HomePage({Key? key, required this.user}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Anasayfa"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text("Hoşgeldiniz ${user.uid}"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The "_user" or "User" parameters are causing problems. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Your code expects to be able to check if `_user` is `null`, so make it nullable. https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety

Comment: How can I do it, can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Dart now supports [null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety) by default. The problem here is you declared a variable `_user` which can't be null but checking it is null or not. You can declare the variable as `User? _user` or call the future code inside a `FutureBuilder` widget.